# Drop rows in DataFrame where two date columns match, otherwise, change value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a df that looks the following,

`df`

```
  id   date      rating_date  rating 
  1  1993-05-20   1993-05-20     3     
  2  1987-03-12   1988-03-12     4    
  3  1994-01-19   1994-10-19     3     
  4  2004-08-03   2004-09-17     2    
  5  2005-10-12   2005-10-12     2
```

I wish to remove the rows where `date` equals `rating_date`, and change `rating` to NR if `rating_date` is > `date`. Would be awesome for some guidance!

```
  id   date      rating_date  rating 
  2  1987-03-12   1988-03-12    NR    
  3  1994-01-19   1994-10-19    NR     
  4  2004-08-03   2004-09-17    NR
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `rating_date` has no chance smaller than `date`, then

```
df = df[df['date'] < df['rating_date']]
df['rating'] = 'NR'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
m=df['date'].ne(df['rating_date'])
df1=df[m].assign(rating='NR')
```

Or simply put

```
df1=df[df['date'].ne(df['rating_date'])].assign(rating='NR')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For removing the rows where `date` equals `rating_date`.

   - Get the list of index where `date` equals to `rating_date`, then drop the rows

   ```
   rows = df[df['date']==df['rating_date']].index.to_list()
   df.drop(rows)
   ```

   - In short

   ```
   df.drop(df[df['date']==df['rating_date']].index.to_list())
   ```
2. For changing `rating` to NR if `rating_date` is > `date`:

   - Get the list of index where 'rating_date' > 'date', then change the value of rows under `rating` to `NR`

   ```
   rows = df[df['rating_date']>df['date']].index.to_list()
   df.loc[rows,'rating'] = 'NR'
   ```